# Distribution of an estimator

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be indenpendent identically distributed random variables with density $$f_X(x)=\theta(1+x)^{-1-\theta}$$ for some $\theta>0$ and $x>0$. I would like to know how to compute the distribution of the estimator $$T=\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+X_i).$$ I have computed the distribution of $\log(1+X)$ but I don't know what to do then.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly found that $\log(1+X_i)$ follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\theta$. Then $T$ is a sum of independent exponential random variable having the same parameter, whose distribution [is known](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27908/sum-of-exponential-random-variables-follows-gamma-confused-by-the-parameters).